# If test on DataFrame that excludes first column

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
raw_data_4iftest=
                                                      Time        F1         F2  
2082-05-03 00:00:59.961599999 2082-05-03 00:00:59.961599999  -83.820000  29.430000      
2082-05-03 00:02:00.009600000 2082-05-03 00:02:00.009600000  -84.330002  28.940001   
2082-05-03 00:02:59.971200000 2082-05-03 00:02:59.971200000  -84.660004  27.940001   
2082-05-03 00:04:00.019200000 2082-05-03 00:04:00.019200000  -84.699997  -84.69999

         dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1440, freq=None, tz=None)
```

I would like to run an if-test on this DataFrame that **excludes the 'Time' column** - i.e. something along the lines of:

```
if (*cells*) in raw_data_4iftest !='datetime64[ns]'    # if cell is **not** a datetime64 object
    raw_data_iftest = raw_data_4iftest >= 0.05
    raw_data_iftest_num = raw_data_iftest.astype(int)
```

So that raw_data_iftest_num returns:

```
raw_data_iftest_num=
                                                      Time  F1 F2  
2082-05-03 00:00:59.961599999 2082-05-03 00:00:59.961599999  0  1      
2082-05-03 00:02:00.009600000 2082-05-03 00:02:00.009600000  0  1   
2082-05-03 00:02:59.971200000 2082-05-03 00:02:59.971200000  0  1
```

Currently, I'm just doing the following:

```
raw_data_iftest = raw_data_4iftest >= 0.05
raw_data_iftest_num = raw_data_iftest.astype(int)
```

but this gives the output below, which doesn't allow me to perform the manipulations I need to to raw_data_iftest_num later in my code:

```
raw_data_iftest_num =

                                  Time  F1 F2  
    2082-05-03 00:00:59.961599999    1  0  1      
    2082-05-03 00:02:00.009600000    1  0  1   
    2082-05-03 00:02:59.971200000    1  0  1
```

I'm pretty new to programming in Python (and using Pandas) so any help/input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select all but the first column of a DataFrame, `df`, you could use

```
df.iloc[:, 1:]
```

---

Or, you could explicitly select the columns you want by name:

```
df[['F1', 'F2']]
```

---

Or remove columns by name:

```
df[[col for col in df if col not in ['Time']]]
```

---

Another alternative is to use
[`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)
to select columns by data type. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time' : np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype='<M8[D]'), 
                   'BBB' : [10,20,30,40],
                   'CCC' : [100,50,-30,-50]})
df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
```

yields

```
   BBB  CCC
0   10  100
1   20   50
2   30  -30
3   40  -50
```

You can also select by excluding columns of dtype `datetime64[ns]`:

```
df.select_dtypes(exclude=['datetime64[ns]'])
```

which yields the same result in this case.

---

So instead of

```
raw_data_iftest = raw_data_4iftest >= 0.05
```

you could use

```
raw_data_iftest = (raw_data_4iftest.iloc[:, 1:] >= 0.05)
```

or

```
raw_data_iftest = (raw_data_4iftest.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]) >= 0.05)
```

Comment: This was very helpful, and also helped my understanding. Thank you. 
Ideally, I do want to keep the 'Time' column though (which I lose when using your suggestions) just not edit it - so that I can use it to take averages based on time later. Is there a way to keep it, or do I have to re-add a time column to this new/your suggested raw_data_iftest now?

Comment: For information, I was able to use your suggestion and (pd.)merge() the resulting DataFrame with another DataFrame to include the 'Time' column again. I'm sure this isn't the easiest way, but it did work.

Comment: Instead of merging, you could reassign the new values to the original DataFrame: `df.iloc[:, 1:] = (df.iloc[:, 1:] > 0.5).astype(int)`